# Rails 3.1 - link_to generates a "no route matches" error on <ActiveRecord::Relation>.first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, link-to

In a view I can do this and the link works fine:

```
<%= link_to "Most popular comment", comment_path( Comment.find(5) ) %>
```

So I know that my routes are set up to show an individual comment record via `comment_path()`.  However when I try this:

```
 <%= link_to "Most popular comment", comment_path( @post.comments.order("vote_cnt DESC").first )
```

I get a "`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}`" error.  But I know this not an accurate error description because the first `link_to()` statement listed above works.  I've confirmed the route exists - from `rake routes` I get this:

```
 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
```

In IRB I can see that the two statements I'm passing to `comment_path()` both generate the same class, namely "`Comment`":

```
irb(main):022:0> top_comment = post.comments.order("vote_cnt DESC").first
  Comment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "post_id" = 2 ORDER BY vote_cnt DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Comment id: 5, heading: nil, body: nil, user_id: 5, created_at: "2012-02-03 01:23:30", updated_at: "2012-02-03 01:23:30",vote_cnt: 0>

irb(main):023:0> top_comment.class
=> Comment(id: integer, heading: string, body: text, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, vote_cnt: integer)

irb(main):024:0> comment_5 = Comment.find(5)
  Comment Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
=> #<Comment id: 5, heading: nil, body: nil, user_id: 5, created_at: "2012-02-03 01:23:30", updated_at: "2012-02-03 01:23:30", vote_cnt: 0>

irb(main):025:0> comment_5.class
=> Comment(id: integer, heading: string, body: text, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, vote_cnt: integer)
```

If both statements generate the same class of object, how can `link_to()` work with one and cause a route error on the other, especially when both resolve to the same exact record?  I tried:

```
<% top_comment = post.comments.order("vote_cnt DESC").first %>
<%= link_to "Most popular comment", comment_path( top_comment )
```

and that generates the same "No path matches..." error.

Any ideas what is going on here?  It seems that `link_to()` works well with a record that comes from a straight up query against a table, but errors out on that same record if was retrieved via an `ActiveRecord::Relation` action. Why?  How can that be?

Comment: Try `@post.comments.order("vote_cnt DESC").first.id`? (That query code should probably be in a controller, but that's another question.)

Comment: Have you define the comment route by resources or match ?

Comment: Sorry guys - programmer logic error.  I tried "rkb"s suggestion of ...first.id, and got an error saying I can't get the ID of a nil object.  This link_to call was in a "@top_ten_posts each do |post|" loop.  Since they are recent posts, one of them didn't have any comments.  Duh!  My code should check for that first.  My bad.  However, it is very frustrating that link_to won't give you a clear indication that you have passed it a nil object.  "No route matches..."?!?!?!  Pretty poor error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[converting my comment above into an answer]

Sorry guys - programmer logic error.

I tried "rkb"s suggestion of ...`first.id`, and got an error saying I can't get the ID of a nil object. This `link_to` call was in a loop:

```
@top_ten_posts each do |post|
...
end
```

Since they are recent posts, one of them didn't have any comments. Duh! My code should check for that first.

My bad. However, it is very frustrating that link_to won't give you a clear indication that you have passed it a nil object. "No route matches..."?!?!?! Pretty poor error message for the situation!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this one is weird. Have you checked what's returned by `@post.comments.order("vote_cnt DESC").first` in your view (either by printing it, or `debugger`/`pry`) ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ksol.  I would have seen the nil record (see my comment above) if I would have tried printing it.  Having a very difficult time getting "debugger" running on my ruby 1.9.3 setup or I would have tried that first.  Thanks for the KISS suggest of just using "puts".

Comment: I moved away from `debugger` a while ago. Using `pry` is very easy and cool, you should give it a shot :)

Comment: I loaded up pry and it is indeed very powerful.  The one thing it is lacking is step/next functionality.  Googling shows a couple of possible solutions to this, but they look sketchy/unmaintained.  Is there a specific  solution you would recommend to get step/next capabilities with pry?